# cx_Oracle: How can I receive each row as a dictionary?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, oop, cx-oracle

By default, cx_Oracle returns each row as a tuple.

```
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> conn=cx_Oracle.connect('scott/tiger')
>>> curs=conn.cursor()
>>> curs.execute("select * from foo");
>>> curs.fetchone()
(33, 'blue')
```

How can I return each row as a dictionary?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can override the cursor's `rowfactory` method.  You will need to do this each time you perform the query.

Here's the results of the standard query, a tuple.

```
curs.execute('select * from foo')
curs.fetchone()
    (33, 'blue')
```

Returning a named tuple:

```
def makeNamedTupleFactory(cursor):
    columnNames = [d[0].lower() for d in cursor.description]
    import collections
    Row = collections.namedtuple('Row', columnNames)
    return Row

curs.rowfactory = makeNamedTupleFactory(curs)
curs.fetchone()
    Row(x=33, y='blue')
```

Returning a dictionary:

```
def makeDictFactory(cursor):
    columnNames = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
    def createRow(*args):
        return dict(zip(columnNames, args))
    return createRow

curs.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(curs)
curs.fetchone()
    {'Y': 'brown', 'X': 1}
```

Credit to Amaury Forgeot d'Arc:
http://sourceforge.net/p/cx-oracle/mailman/message/27145597

Answer (score 16):

A very short version:

```
curs.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip([d[0] for d in curs.description], args))
```

Tested on Python 3.7.0 & cx_Oracle 7.1.2

Comment: Placing this line after the "curs.execute" has worked for me. Returns list of dicts. Thanks.

Comment: Can you make this answer complete and independent from the others?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Old question but adding some helpful links with a Python recipe</sup>

According to `cx_Oracle` documentation:

> #### [Cursor.rowfactory](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.rowfactory)
>
> This read-write attribute specifies a method to call for each row that
>   is retrieved from the database. **Ordinarily a tuple is returned** for
>   each row but **if this attribute is set, the method is called with the
>   tuple that would normally be returned, and the result of the method is
>   returned instead**.

The [cx_Oracle - Python Interface for Oracle Database](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/) Also points to GitHub repository for lots of helpful [sample](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle) examples. Please check [GenericRowFactory.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/GenericRowFactory.py).

Googled: This PPT can be further helpful: [<sup>[PDF]</sup>CON6543 Python and Oracle Database - RainFocus](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow16/sess/1464899218456001XoGM/ppt/201609-OOW-CON6543-Python-Oracle-Database.pdf)

#### Recipe

Django database backend for Oracle under the hood uses cx_Oracle. In earlier versions ( Django 1.11- ) they have written [**`_rowfactory(cursor, row)`**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/4523f63814037ed833b8bb55273c09a43dd69fb0/lib/django-1.5/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py#795) That also cast cx_Oracle's numeric data types into relevant Python data and strings into unicode.

If you have installed Django Please check base.py as follows:

```
$ DJANGO_DIR="$(python -c 'import django, os; print(os.path.dirname(django.__file__))')"
$ vim $DJANGO_DIR/db/backends/oracle/base.py
```

One can borrow `_rowfactory()` from `$DJANGO_DIR/db/backends/oracle/base.py` and can apply below decorator `naming` to make it return `namedtuple` instead of simple `tuple`.

mybase.py

```
import functools
from itertools import izip, imap
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import namedtuple
import cx_Oracle as Database
import decimal

def naming(rename=False, case=None):
    def decorator(rowfactory):
        @functools.wraps(rowfactory)
        def decorated_rowfactory(cursor, row, typename="GenericRow"):
            field_names = imap(case, imap(itemgetter(0), cursor.description))
            return namedtuple(typename, field_names)._make(rowfactory(cursor, row))
        return decorated_rowfactory
    return decorator
```

use it as:

```
@naming(rename=False, case=str.lower)
def rowfactory(cursor, row):
   casted = []
   ....
   ....
   return tuple(casted)
```

oracle.py

```
import cx_Oracle as Database
from cx_Oracle import *
import mybase

class Cursor(Database.Cursor):

    def execute(self, statement, args=None):
        prepareNested = (statement is not None and self.statement != statement)
        result = super(self.__class__, self).execute(statement, args or [])
        if prepareNested:
            if self.description:
                self.rowfactory = lambda *row: mybase.rowfactory(self, row)
        return result

    def close(self):
        try:
            super(self.__class__, self).close()
        except Database.InterfaceError:
            "already closed"

class Connection(Database.Connection):

    def cursor(self):
        Cursor(self)

connect = Connection
```

Now, instead of import cx_oracle import oracle in user script as:

user.py

```
import oracle

dsn = oracle.makedsn('HOSTNAME', 1521, service_name='dev_server')
db = connect('username', 'password', dsn)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
  SELECT 'Grijesh' as FirstName, 
         'Chauhan' as LastName,
         CAST('10560.254' AS NUMBER(10, 2)) as Salary
  FROM DUAL
""")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print ("First Name is %s" % row.firstname) # => Grijesh
print ("Last Name is %s" % row.lastname) # => Chauhan
print ("Salary is %r" % row.salary) # => Decimal('10560.25')
```

Give it a Try!!

Answer (score 1):

Building up on answer by @maelcum73 :

```
curs.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip([d[0] for d in curs.description], args))
```

The issue with this solution is that you need to re-set this *after every execution*.

Going one step further, you can create a shell around the cursor object like so:

```
    class dictcur(object):
        # need to monkeypatch the built-in execute function to always return a dict
        def __init__(self, cursor):
            self._original_cursor = cursor

        def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # rowfactory needs to be set AFTER EACH execution!
            self._original_cursor.execute(*args, **kwargs)
            self._original_cursor.rowfactory = lambda *a: dict(
                zip([d[0] for d in self._original_cursor.description], a)
            )
            # cx_Oracle's cursor's execute method returns a cursor object
            # -> return the correct cursor in the monkeypatched version as well!
            return self._original_cursor

        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            # anything other than the execute method: just go straight to the cursor
            return getattr(self._original_cursor, attr)
    dict_cursor = dictcur(cursor=conn.cursor())
```

Using this `dict_cursor`, every subsequent `dict_cursor.execute()` call will return a dictionary. Note: I tried monkeypatching the execute method directly, however that was not possible because it is a built-in method.