# How does cursor.rowfactory (cx_oracle) work in returning each row in dictionary format?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

How does that work? I have looked up the documentation. It said the *cursor.rowfactory* is an attribute letting user define how the format of the row is retrieved. However I don't see any examples to how to define it. Then I found the answer above. I totally lost track and had no idea what that is doing. Can anyone explain what is that doing? What is the attribute `.rowfactory`? And how `makeDictFactory` works? What is `createRow` doing and what `args` contains?
Is there some documents I can look up?

```python
def makeDictFactory(cursor):
    columnNames = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
    def createRow(*args):
       return dict(zip(columnNames, args))
    return createRow

curs.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(curs)
curs.fetchone()
```

[Code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045879/cx-oracle-how-can-i-receive-each-row-as-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/GenericRowFactory.py

Also check out the cx_Oracle tutorial https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial

Also see presentations on cx_Oracle like https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow18/sess/1523651275582001fu8I/PF/TIP4076%20-%20Python%20and%20Oracle%20Database%20on%20the%20Table_1540587368635001aNOw.pdf