# SQL Dictionary Appending for Large Datasets in a Loop in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle

I am trying to append dictionaries together and then use "from_dict" to get the final returned data from cx_Oracle as I heard that is more efficient that appending each returned row from SQL. However, my loop still takes a very long time (the ending loop returns a VERY large database, each loop gets data for an I.D. which returns ~ 12,000 rows per I.D. - there are over 700 I.D.s in the loop). How do I take advantage of "from_dict" so this speeds up? I don't think this is the most efficient way to do this as I have the code written now. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Is there a more efficient way? Using `concat` and not `append`?

```
for iteration, c in enumerate(l, start = 1):
   total = len(l)
   data['SP_ID'] = c
   data['BEGIN_DATE'] = BEGIN_DATE
   print("Getting consumption data for service point I.D.:", c, " ---->", iteration, "of", total)
   cursor.arraysize = 1000000
   cursor.prefetchrows = 2
   cursor.execute(sql, data)
   cursor.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip([d[0] for d in cursor.description], args))
   df_row = cursor.fetchall()
   if len(df_row) == 0:
      pass
   else:
      a = {k: [d[k] for d in df_row] for k in df_row[0]} # Here is where I combine dictionaries, but this is for only dataset pulling from SQL.I want to combine all the dictionaries from each loop to increase efficiency.
      AMI_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
      #AMI.append(AMI_data)
      #final_AMI_data = pd.concat(AMI)
      # final_data.dropna(inplace = True)

# UPDATED

final_AMI_data = pd.DataFrame()

for iteration, c in enumerate(l, start = 1):
   total = len(l)
   data['SP_ID'] = c
   data['BEGIN_DATE'] = BEGIN_DATE
   print("Getting consumption data for service point I.D.:", c, " ---->", iteration, "of", total)
   cursor.arraysize = 1000000
   cursor.prefetchrows = 2
   cursor.execute(sql, data)
   cursor.rowfactory = lambda *args: dict(zip([d[0] for d in cursor.description], args))
   df_row = cursor.fetchall()
   if len(df_row) == 0:
      pass
   else:
      AMI_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df_row)
      final_AMI_data.append(AMI_data, ignore_index = False)
      # final_data.dropna(inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to re-create your dictionary if you've already the dict-style cursor factory. (Btw, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35046018/1431750) for how to make a better one.)

Assuming your `df_rows` looks like this after fetching all rows, with 'X' and 'Y' being example column names for the query-result:

```
[{'X': 'xval1', 'Y': 'yval1'},
 {'X': 'xval2', 'Y': 'yval2'},
 {'X': 'xval3', 'Y': 'yval3'}]
```

**1.** Then use [**`.from_records()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to create your dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(df_rows)
```

Output:

```
       X      Y
0  xval1  yval1
1  xval2  yval2
2  xval3  yval3
```

That way, you don't need to restructure your results to use with `from_dict()`.

**2.** And if you want to keep adding each group of 12,000 results to the same DataFrame, use [`DataFrame.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with `ignore_index=True` to keep adding each new group of results to the existing dataframe.

It's better to just append into your dataframe instead of creating a bigger and bigger dictionaryto finally create one df.

---

In case it wasn't clear, **remove** these two lines in your `else`:

```
a = {k: [d[k] for d in df_row] for k in df_row[0]}
AMI_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
```

and replace it with just:

```
AMI_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df_row)
# and then to add it to your final:
final_AMI_data.append(AMI_data, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! So, ```df_row``` returns a dictionary per row. So I use ```a = {k: [d[k] for d in df_row] for k in df_row[0]}``` to merge those into one. The problem is that each I.D. returns a list of dictionaries.

Comment: My point was - you can skip that step. In the example I've given for `df_row`, it is "one dictionary per row" which is what `from_records` can use directly to make your df.

Comment: Provide a sample (2-3 rows) of what your `df_row` looks like **if it's not similar** to the format I've shown: list of dicts where each dict key is the sql query column name and the value for that key is the column value.

Comment: There are 12,000 of these per ```l``` in the loop (12,000 rows per I.D.).

Comment: And that format will work fine for `from_records`.

Comment: ```TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments``` - not sure why this is happening. I know append can take arguments.

Comment: Did you initialise `final_AMI_data` with `final_AMI_data = []` ? That makes it a list and then `final_AMI_data.append()` would call Python's `list.append()`, which is not what you want. Initialise it as an empty dataframe with `final_AMI_data = pd.DataFrame()`.

Comment: I've updated the code and now ```final_AMI_data``` is empty after the loop? See above with updated code.

Comment: No idea why. Print `len(final_AMI_data)` and `len(AMI_data)` after each loop and see if it's working at all. Nothing in the code above would indicate why the final one is empty at the end. Check your indentation, check for typos. So it's not something StackOverflow can solve.